# cyclic dependency creating bottlenecks for multithreading

Tags: cyclic

There are two classes A & B:-

1) A contains B. A carries out 2 operations on B ... insert(data) into B's map and later replace that data.

2) Along with this A also has a map in which it insert/replaces the data that it feeds to B

3) B after carrying out insert/replace calls A's methods which in turn could call insert/replace on B.

Due to this stack is getting full and I am getting segmentaion fault..

Can anyone suggest some  better design paradigm.

Hope I have explained my question well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a logical problem, not a programming problem. No design pattern can solve this for you.

You have to decide when this cycle shall stop. When is it inappropriate to call the other class?

Ask yourself why they call each other infinitely often. If you really know what you're doing, you can use such a ping pong mechanism. But after a few calls it should stabilize and stop calling the other class.